# C++ overloading += operator in custom string class better implementation

Tags: c++, strings, reinventing-the-wheel, overloading

I am trying to learn C++, so I started coding a custom string class (using only c-style strings) to get familiar with concepts like operator overloading etc. in the case we have a pointer attribute. I wanted to know if there is a smarter/better/neater way to implement the += operator (or the others).

So I am basically defining a private char pointer to store the c-style string, two constructors (empty, char* arg), a copy constructor, a move constructor, a destructor (to deallocate the allocated space from the heap) and two operators (to concatenate strings).

**mystring.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class mystring
{
private:
    char* str;

public:
    mystring();
    mystring(char* str);
    mystring(const mystring &s);
    mystring(mystring &&s) noexcept;
    ~mystring();

    mystring& operator=(const mystring &s);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const mystring &s);

    mystring operator+(const mystring &s);
    mystring& operator+=(const mystring &s);
};
```

**mystring.cpp**

```
#include "mystring.h"

mystring::mystring() : mystring(nullptr) {};

mystring::mystring(char* str) : str{nullptr}
{
    if(str == nullptr){
        this->str = new char;
        this->str = '\0';
    }else {
        this->str = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
        strcpy(this->str, str);
    }
}

// Deep copy
mystring::mystring(const mystring &s) : str{nullptr}
{
    if(str == nullptr){
        this->str = new char;
        *(this->str) = '\0';
    }else {
        this->str = new char[strlen(s.str) + 1];
        strcpy(this->str, s.str);
    }
}

// Move constructor
mystring::mystring(mystring &&s) noexcept : str{s.str} { s.str = nullptr; }


mystring::~mystring() { delete [] str; }


mystring& mystring::operator=(const mystring &s){
    if(this != &s){
        this->str = new char[strlen(s.str) + 1];
        strcpy(this->str, s.str); 
    }

    return *this;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const mystring &s){
    out << s.str;
    return out;
}


mystring mystring::operator+(const mystring &s){
    mystring concat;
    concat.str = new char[strlen(this->str) + strlen(s.str) + 1];
    strcpy(concat.str, this->str);
    strcat(concat.str, s.str);
    return concat;
}

mystring& mystring::operator+=(const mystring &s){
    
    // temp save "this" string to other
    mystring other {new char(strlen(this->str) + 1)};
    strcpy(other.str, this->str);

    // allocate space for the concatenated string
    this->str = new char[strlen(this->str) + strlen(s.str) + 1];

    // move "this" and input strings to "this"
    strcpy(this->str, other.str);
    strcat(this->str, s.str);
    
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did a single-null-allocation correctly(ish) once:

```
if(str == nullptr){
    this->str = new char;
    *(this->str) = '\0';
```

and incorrectly a second time:

```
if(str == nullptr){
    this->str = new char;
    this->str = '\0';
```

This will produce a memory leak. That aside, if your compiler allowed this without yelling about incompatible types, that makes me sad.

Even then, as @TobySpeight indicates, the first style of allocation has a mismatch with your `delete[]` and also needs to follow array-like syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the representation (null-terminated `char*`, like C) is that it's inefficient for concatenation.

If we use array+length, as is common for strings in many languages (including the C++ standard library), then we don't need to seek to the end for every operation (as we do here, hidden inside `strcat()` - even though we've already computed the length!).  Read about the problems with "[Schlemiel the Painter](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm)" and his algorithm.

Converting null pointer into empty string is a good idea, avoiding special-case handling throughout the code.  But there's a serious bug:

> ```
>     this->str = new char;
> ```

We need `new char[1]` there, because `new[]` and `delete[]` go together as a pair.

This mismatch would be caught by Valgrind - I really recommend you exercise your code using a memory checker any time you write memory management code (that's every time you use a naked `new` or `new[]`; also if you ever use `std::malloc()` or any C libraries that haven't been wrapped in a RAII wrapper).

Why do we have `mystring(mystring&&)` but no `operator=(mystring&&)`?  It doesn't make sense to have a move constructor but always force copying for assignment.

Style-wise, I don't like use of `this->` all over the place - that's just distracting clutter that can be avoided by giving arguments different names to members.